# Load gif image from sdcard - android

Tags: android

When i open  app ,i've downlaod some gif image and stored on sd card.

i've checked some url

http://androidosbeginning.blogspot.in/2010/09/gif-animation-in-android.html
http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-how-to-use-animated-gif/

but in this url  example , the gif images loading from drawable folder.

How to load gif image from sd card?

When i use inputstream like

```
 File file=new File("sdcardpat");
    InputStream is=new FileInputStream(file);
    Movie.decodeStream(is);
```

i got below error

```
08-14 13:20:41.621: W/System.err(6052): java.io.IOException
08-14 13:20:41.621: W/System.err(6052):     at java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:218)
08-14 13:20:41.621: W/System.err(6052):     at android.graphics.Movie.decodeStream(Native Method)
08-14 13:20:41.621: W/System.err(6052):     at com.android.gif.GIFDemo$GIFView.<init>(GIFDemo.java:84)
08-14 13:20:41.621: W/System.err(6052):     at com.android.gif.GIFDemo$1.run(GIFDemo.java:36)
08-14 13:20:41.621: W/System.err(6052):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-14 13:20:41.621: W/System.err(6052):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-14 13:20:41.621: W/System.err(6052):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 13:20:41.621: W/System.err(6052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-14 13:20:41.621: W/System.err(6052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 13:20:41.621: W/System.err(6052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 13:20:41.621: W/System.err(6052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-14 13:20:41.621: W/System.err(6052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-14 13:20:41.621: W/System.err(6052):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you have requisite permissions to access the image in SD card ?  First you gotta check that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774471/issue-while-reading-an-excel-file-in-android/17785567#17785567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw first link you making movie from an InputStream and drawing movie on canvas. InputStream may be anything. If you want to use Image from sdcards then use FileInputStream like below code

```
    File file=new File("sdcardpat");
    InputStream is=new FileInputStream(file);
    Movie.decodeStream(is);
```

Comment: hi when i use fileinputstream its throws error. pls check my question.

Comment: i've added the error in my question. @sameer its throws ioexception. i've give correct path.

Comment: It seems you did not gave the correct path of images. Please make sure you have the file on given path

Comment: File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();  
            File file = new File(dir,"weather.gif");

            String pathName = file.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d("rvg", "PN: "+pathName);
            if(file.exists())
            {
            movie=Movie.decodeFile(pathName);
            is1=context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.animated_gif);

            movie1=Movie.decodeStream(is1);
            }

Comment: I've checked the file is exist or not. if exist only i've pass the pathname.

Comment: i've arised question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233738/ioexception-when-creating-movie-from-filepath-android

Comment: When conveting input stream, need to give buffer size.InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(getCacheDir(), "mygif.gif")), 16 * 1024);
        is.mark(16 * 1024); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
movie = Movie.decodeStream(is);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `GifMovieView` you can make it work like this. I also had problems but doing it like this it's working:

```
        mAdMovie = (GifMovieView) findViewById(R.id.movie_ad);

        //Decode gif to Movie
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(mAdsManager.getCurrentAdvertisingFullPath());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException mE) {
            mE.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.mark(100000);
        Movie movie = Movie.decodeStream(bis);
        mAdMovie.setMovie(movie);
```

Original answer [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/aMljuKzXRG8)